# CallBack функция как член класса

Tags: callback, c++

Возможно ли использовать CallBack вызовы при написании своих классов (на С++, под OS Windows)?
К примеру реализовать таймер при использовании Callback в своём классе!?

```
  SetTimer(NULL, 0, 1000, (TIMERPROC) TimerProc)
  void CALLBACK TimerProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT idEvent, DWORD dwTime)
```

Comment: Можно поконкретнее, что за CallBack функция?

Comment: Callback - функция обратного вызова, @mikillskegg - неужели вы этого не знали?О_о

Comment: Видимо @mikillskegg и не знал, потому что, как мне кажется в Unix системах такого нет! :)

Comment: Когда кажется крестится нужно :D

Причем тут unix? LOL?

Comment: Высокопараллельные научные вычисления с применением CUDA и OpenMP. Основная рабочая среда - Linux Xubuntu. Основной язык - С/С++.
Этим занимается @mikillskegg !

Comment: @AlexWindHope  Ещё спроси откуда я это узнал :)

Comment: Действительно, причём тут unix, если linux xubuntu? (В линуксе нет кодов из древних манускриптов вестерн электрик.)

Comment: Умники и знатоки, вы автору вопроса будете отвечать?

Кстати, callback functions есть в GTK+

Comment: У меня тоже похожий вопрос но намного более хитрый. Дело в том что ситуация похожа на Вашу, только: нужно передать указатель на функцию-член класса X в качестве аргумента функции-члену класса A. В классе A нужно вызвать функцию-член класса X, только вот класс A ничего не знает про тип X, он знает только указатель на функцию и ну и возможно указатель на объект X только в виде void* (не знаяы о типе класса X. Так как класс A - у меня собственный библиотечный класс, а класс X - клиентский код, который пишет пользователь библиотеки.

Comment: Можно конкретный пример? Вообще вероятно, что если требуется такой изврат, то есть изъян в архитектуре. Ну, и всегда можно обойти проблему.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В общем виде передать указатель на нестатический, наверное, не получится. Но конкретно описываемую Вами задачу можно решить, например, так. Экземпляры классов, которые хотят получать уведомления от таймера регистрируются в некотором словаре, получая при этом идентификатор таймера. Обработчик таймера находит получателя по идентификатору таймера и переадресует вызов ему. Грубый пример:

```
static int s_counter = 0;
map<int, ITimerReciever* > s_receivers;
class ITimerReciever
{
    public:
       virtual void OnTimer() = 0;
}

static void AdviseToTimer(UINT elapse, ITimerReceiver * pReceiver)
{
    receivers[++s_counter] = pReceiver;
    SetTimer(NULL, s_counter, elapse, (TIMERPROC) TimerProc);
}

void CALLBACK TimerProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT idEvent, DWORD dwTime) {
      receivers[idEvent]->OnTimer();
  }
```

Comment: Вообще-то, делать что-либо серьезное в асинхронном обработчике не самая хорошая идея. 

Среда времени исполнения С++ может ту еще свинью подложить.

Comment: @avp а где тут асинхронный обработчик? Win32 таймер - очень даже синхронный

Comment: @ganouver а что, обработчик Win32 таймера вызывается не в неизвестном заранее (в смысле потока управления программы) месте ?

Объясните тогда, что Вы считаете асинхронным ?

Comment: @avp обработчик Win32 таймера обрабатывается, как и все сообщения Windows, в порядке выборки сообщений из очереди в интерфейсном потоке. Т.е. все сообщения обрабатываются последовательно, следовательно - синхронно, т.е. нет необходимости использовать примитивы синхронизации для защите ресурсов при одновременном доступе из разных потоков. Существуют асинхронные реализации таймеров, когда для таймера запускается отдельный поток и обработчик будет вызван не в том потоке, в котором создавался таймер. Но это уже тема отдельного разговора.

Comment: Их-то я и имел в виду (по аналогии с сигналами в \*nix).

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, требуется использовать методы класса как функции обратного вызова. Это стандартная вещь:

```
 class Example {
 public:
     static void member();
 };

 int main()
 {
     signal(SIGINT, Example::member);
 }
```

Comment: В общем нужно что то типа:

      class MyTimer{
      public:
       void CALLBACK TimerProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT idEvent, DWORD dwTime) {
        A=5;
       }
       void StartTimer(){
        A=0;
        id = SetTimer(NULL, 0, 1000, (TIMERPROC) TimerProc);
       }
      private:
       UINT id;
       UINT A;
      }

Comment: Хитро придумал !? :)

Answer (score 0):

@reije, хочу конкретный пример что хотите сделать. В общем случае - это плохая идея. С другой стороны, запросто можно получить адрес static-функции-члена класса, но есть нюанс, связанный с тем, что статическая ф-ция может получить доступ только к статическим членам класса. Т.е. по сути мы всего лишь засовываем нашу чудесную обычную функцию в namespace класса. Другой вопрос, что static ф-ция может получить доступ к каждому объекту своего типа, но это придется реализовать самостоятельно.

Прекрасный пример использования возможностей С++ для реализации callback'ов предложен на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189440/c-class-member-callback-simple-examples). Используются шаблоны `std::function` и `std::bind`

В качестве обходных путей предлагается реализовать:

- паттерн [observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)
- [систему событий и их обработчиков](http://cratonica.wordpress.com/2010/02/19/implementing-c-net-events-in-c/)

Comment: Да в том то и дело, что есть множество библиотек, которые написаны на C (в частности WinAPI), которые принимают указатель на функцию. Поэтому callable объекты С++ (в частности std::function), туда передавать нельзя. Почти нельзя: я давно читал статью, где так делали при помощи какого-то грязного хака, но что-то найти не получается.

Comment: Ну, дык - тут все ясно. У Си то есть стандарт на ABI, а у С++ его и нет. Так что получается нужно делать промежуточный слой. 

Кстати, ведь чтобы не передавать указатели на обычные ф-ции члены класса есть две серьезных причины - это их сигнатура, содержащая *this (callback'и все повально какого-то предварительно определенного типа) и то что может вмешаться сама структура классов (там всякие полиморфизмы и наследования)

Answer (score -1):

Да конечно, можно.

Comment: Каким образом ?